# SBT sourceGenerators task - execute only if a file changes

Tags: scala, sbt

In my SBT project, I have an input file `src/main/greeting/Greeting.txt` with the following content:

```
Hello, world!
```

This is my `build.sbt` that generates Scala source from the `Greeting.txt` file:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task{
  println("GENERATING FILES")
  val inputFile = file("src/main/greeting/Greeting.txt")
  val generatedFile =
    (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "scala" / "Main.scala"
  val greeting = IO.read(inputFile).trim
  IO.write(
    generatedFile,
    s"""object Main extends App { println("${greeting}") }"""
  )
  Seq(generatedFile)
}.taskValue
```

This `build.sbt` works fine, except that it runs my tasks to generate the Scala sources **every time** I compile/run my project. I would like it to only run these tasks when the `Greeting.txt`-file has changed. How can I achieve this?

---

#### MCVE

Bash-script that generates the project:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir sourceGeneratorsExample
cd sourceGeneratorsExample
mkdir -p src/main/scala
mkdir -p src/main/greeting
echo "Hello, world!" >> src/main/greeting/Greeting.txt
cat <<HEREDOC > build.sbt
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task{
  println("GENERATING FILES")
  val inputFile = file("src/main/greeting/Greeting.txt")
  val generatedFile =
    (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "scala" / "Main.scala"
  val greeting = IO.read(inputFile).trim
  IO.write(
    generatedFile,
    "object Main extends App { println(\"" + greeting + "\") }"
  )
  Seq(generatedFile)
}.taskValue
HEREDOC
```

---

#### Duplicates / Documentation

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11646790/2707792) is an answer from 2012, a lot has changed since then.
- The [current reference manual](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-reference.pdf) advises to use *"`sbt.Tracked.{ inputChanged, outputChanged }`
  etc"*, but does not expand on that, and the `Tracked` object is not mentioned anywhere else in the manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make custom task avoid redoing work if the input files are unchanged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640715/how-to-make-custom-task-avoid-redoing-work-if-the-input-files-are-unchanged)

Comment: Here's an example, from a build of my own, of how to combine `sourceGenerators` with `FileFunction.cached`: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo-Headless/blob/fc68dd8a4f247c3eed4363205fa96acca67cf254/jvm/generators.sbt#L5-L16

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`FileFunction.cached`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.2.8/api/sbt/util/FileFunction$.html), which is a:

> Generic change-detection helper used to help build / artifact generation / etc. steps detect whether or not they need to run.

It uses a cache folder, where SBT automatically keeps a record of the file changes. With `FileFunction.cached`, your `build.sbt` might look like this:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task{

  // * Create a cached function which generates the output files
  //   only if the input files have changed.
  // * The first parameter is a file instance of the path to
  //   the cache folder
  // * The second parameter is the function to process the input 
  //   files and return the output files
  val cachedFun = FileFunction.cached(
    streams.value.cacheDirectory / "greeting"
  ) { (in: Set[File]) =>

    println("GENERATING FILES")

    val generatedFile =
      (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "scala" / "Main.scala"
    val greeting = IO.read(in.head).trim
    IO.write(
      generatedFile,
      "object Main extends App { println(\"" + greeting + "\") }"
    )
    Set(generatedFile)
  }

  // get the input file
  val inputFile = file("src/main/greeting/Greeting.txt")

  // put the input file into a `Set` (as required by `cachedFun`),
  // pass it to the `cachedFun`,
  // convert the result to `Seq` (as required by `Def.task`)
  cachedFun(Set(inputFile)).toSeq

}.taskValue
```

The first parameter for `FileFunction.cached` is a directory that will be used to store cache information (e.g. hashes of the input files). Here, we passed `streams.value.cacheDirectory / "greeting"`, which will create a cache subdirectory somewhere inside of the `target`-directory. The advantage is that his directory will be automatically cleaned when the task `clean` is run.

The first argument list of the `cached` method takes two additional optional `inStyle` and `outStyle` arguments, which determine how changes are detected (e.g. by modification date, or by comparing hashes). Note that in older versions of SBT, these two arguments are mandatory, so that your `cachedFun` would look somewhat like this:

```
val cachedFun = FileFunction.cached(
  cacheBaseDirectory = streams.value.cacheDirectory / "greeting",
  inStyle = FilesInfo.lastModified,
  outStyle = FilesInfo.exists
)(cachedFunBodyImpl)
```

The second argument list of the `FileFunction.cached`-method takes a function that maps a `Set` of input files to the `Set` of output files. It is invoked only if the input files have changed.

You can find more info for an older version of SBT [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/faq.html#how-can-a-task-avoid-redoing-work-if-the-input-files-are-unchanged) (SBT 0.13.5), which expands on `cached` and file tracking styles. Quoting:

> There are two additional arguments for the first parameter list that allow the file tracking style to be explicitly specified. By default, the input tracking style is FilesInfo.lastModified, based on a file's last modified time, and the output tracking style is FilesInfo.exists, based only on whether the file exists. The other available style is FilesInfo.hash, which tracks a file based on a hash of its contents.

---

The first code snippet has been tested using SBT 1.2.8. The second code snippet should also work with earlier 0.13.x versions.

Comment: In `cachedFun`, is it possible to execute another task?  My code generation involves running a full Java program.  Sbt already has the class path set up, so in theory, I just need to do `(genProj / run in Compile).toTask("").value` but that gives me errors about an illegal dynamic access.