# How to create sources from resources (or other project files) in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to generate sources from files which are part of the project (I have currently placed them in a resource directory, but this is not a requirement).

This is my attempt on it:

```
sourceGenerators in Test += (sourceManaged in Test map { src =>
  (unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test).value map { dir =>
    val file = dir / "demo" / src.name
    IO.write(file, "Prefix---" + IO.read(src) + "---Postfix")
    file
  }
}).taskValue
```

This gives me an error:

```
error: Illegal dynamic dependency 
(unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test).value map { src =>
```

What is a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has worked eventually is this (inspired by [this code](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo-Headless/blob/fc68dd8a4f247c3eed4363205fa96acca67cf254/jvm/generators.sbt), referenced in a comment to a question [SBT sourceGenerators task - execute only if a file changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897874/sbt-sourcegenerators-task-execute-only-if-a-file-changes)):

```
sourceGenerators in Test += Def.task {
  val sources = (unmanagedResources in Test).value filter ( _.isFile )
  val dir = (sourceManaged in Test).value
  sources map { src =>
    IO.write(dir / src.name, "Prefix---" + IO.read(src) + "---Postfix")
    f
  }
}.taskValue
```

The important part was reading the settings inside of the task.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dynamic tasks are the correct way to do it
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Dynamic+Computations+with

Comment: I hope you are right, but would you be able to give a more concrete example? I was not successful in my experiments with them so far.